# How to blend colors based on their distance to camera with shaders?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I am currently using Three JS [VolumeShader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/shaders/VolumeShader.js) module which provides maximum intensity projection (MIP) rendering. So along a ray through the object, only the maximum value voxel will be displayed. I have been trying to modify the `cast_mip` function from the module so that it displays a blending of all the voxels in the ray's path by weighting the voxels closest to the camera as more important and the farthest as least important. So if there is a lot of blue closest to the surface with redder color inside, the surface should primarily look blue with a tinge of red. The following is from the fragment shader which is what I have been trying to modify from [VolumeShader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/shaders/VolumeShader.js):

```
void cast_mip(vec3 start_loc, vec3 step, int nsteps, vec3 view_ray) {
    float max_val = 0.0;
    vec3 loc = start_loc; // Starting at the surface of the cube

    for (int iter=0; iter<MAX_STEPS; iter++) {
        if (iter >= nsteps) // Controls opacity through volume
            break;
                                
        // Sample from the 3D texture
        float val = sample1(loc); // val represents Nrrd value at location loc

        // Apply MIP operation
        if (val > max_val) {
            max_val = val;
        }

        // Advance location deeper into the volume (moving from surface to inside)
        loc += step;

        // Trying to blend the value using weighted average
        //max_val += val/distance(start_loc, loc);
    }                       

    // Resolve final color
    gl_FragColor = apply_colormap(max_val);
}
```

Here is an example of MIP rendering of a rectangular prism with voxel values increasing successively layer by layer from bottom to top from 0 to 13. The image on the right is what you see from bottom or top view which will be red because it is showing the maximum value through the model as expected:

[image] [image]

When I try to remove the MIP rendering and replace it with my strategy `//max_val += val/distance(start_loc, loc);`, I get the following where everything looks red and the top and bottom are always blue. I expect the top view to look more redish because that's where higher values reside, and the bottom view should look more bluish since that is where the lower values reside. The sides should appear blended depending on the camera's position:

[image] [image]

The following are the relevant variables defined in the `void main()` fragment shader function below:

```
// Normalize clipping plane info
    vec3 farpos = v_farpos.xyz / v_farpos.w;
    vec3 nearpos = v_nearpos.xyz / v_nearpos.w;

    // Calculate unit vector pointing in the view direction through this fragment.
    vec3 view_ray = normalize(nearpos.xyz - farpos.xyz);

    // Compute the (negative) distance to the front surface or near clipping plane.
    // v_position is the back face of the cuboid, so the initial distance calculated in the dot
    // product below is the distance from near clip plane to the back of the cuboid
    float distance = dot(nearpos - v_position, view_ray);
    distance = max(distance, min((-0.5 - v_position.x) / view_ray.x,
                            (u_size.x - 0.5 - v_position.x) / view_ray.x));

    distance = max(distance, min((-0.5 - v_position.y) / view_ray.y,
                            (u_size.y - 0.5 - v_position.y) / view_ray.y));

    distance = max(distance, min((-0.5 - v_position.z) / view_ray.z,
                            (u_size.z - 0.5 - v_position.z) / view_ray.z));

    // Now we have the starting position on the front surface
    vec3 front = v_position + view_ray * distance;

    // Decide how many steps to take (relative_step_size = 1.0)
    int nsteps = int(-distance / relative_step_size + 0.5);

    // Get starting location and step vector in texture coordinates
    vec3 step = ((v_position - front) / u_size) / float(nsteps);

    //u_size is vec3 describing length, width, height of model
    vec3 start_loc = front / u_size;
```

Comment: max_val would have to start at 0, not -1e6

Comment: Made the change. I have the same results

Comment: what kind of values does `distance(...)` return?

Comment: The first distance is going to be 0 so val/0 is infinity or NaN

Comment: ```distance()``` returns a float value representing the distance between two points. I have also moved the ```max_val += val/distance(start_loc, loc);``` beneath the ```loc += step;``` so that it is not infinity at the beginning.